# Divisibility Rule for 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I'm working through an elementary number theory course right now and I think I've come up with a proof here but wanted some feedback on my logic.

Question:  If the sum of the digits in base 10 is divisible by 9, then the number itself is divisible by 9.

Proof: Suppose that $9|d_1+d_2+...+d_n$ then $d_1+d_2+...+d_n=0\mod9$

Now consider $d_1(10^{n-1})+d_2(10^{n-2})+...+d_{(n-1)}(10^1)+d_n(10^0)$
Each power of $10$ is equivalent to $1\mod9$

therefor

$d_1(10^{n-1})+d_2(10^{n-2})+...+d_{(n-1)}(10^1)+d_n(10^0)=(1\mod9)(d_1+d_2+...d_n)$

$9|(d_1+d_2+...d_n)$ by our assumption, thus $9|(1\mod9)(d_1+d_2+...d_n)$

Thus we have shown that if 9 divides the sum of the digits in base 10, 9 divides the number itself.

The only question I really have is whether I'm jumping the gun on my assumption concerning the powers of 10 being $1\mod 9$.  I think this is fair game here but not 100% confident.  Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is fine.  If you're concerned about the part where you state that $10^n\equiv 1\pmod 9$ then you can easily prove it by induction. Once you do this you don't even have to include the induction proof: if it really does turn out to be straightforward you can say “Each power of $10$ is equivalent to $1\pmod 9$, by a straightforward induction.”

Comment: One way to see what's going on is to imagine you're given a number $n$ and you decide to write out the number $(10^n - 1)$.  The result will be just a bunch of $9$'s...and a number like that will be divisible by $9$.  So $10^n$ must be equivalent to $1$ mod $9$.  (For a formal proof of this fact, you could use induction on $n$, as @MJD says.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\,{\rm mod}\ 9\!:\ \color{}{10\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{10^n}\equiv 1^n \color{#c00}{\equiv 1},\,$ therefore

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \  d_n \color{#c00}{10^n} + d_1\color{#c00}{10} + d_0$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad \quad  \equiv\,\ d_k +\cdots + d_1 + d_0\ \ $ by $ $ [basic Congruence Rules.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

More efficiently, we can observe that the decimal (radix $10)$ representation of an integer $N$ is a *polynomial* function $\,f(10)\,$ of the radix, with *integer* coefficients (digits) $\,d_i,\,$ i.e.

$$\begin{eqnarray} N\, =\, f(10) \!\!\!&&= d_n 10^n +\,\cdots+d_1 10 + d_0 \\ {\rm where}\ \ f(x) \!\!&&= d_n\, x^n\,+\,\cdots\,+d_1\, x\, + d_0\end{eqnarray}$$

Thus $\ {\rm mod}\ 9\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{10\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, f(\color{#c00}{10})\equiv f(\color{#c00}{1}) = d_n+\cdots + d_1 \equiv\,$ sum of digits, which follows by applying the [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

The proof works for *any polynomial* $\,f(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients. As such, these tests for divisibility by the radix$\pm1$ (e.g. also casting out nines) may be viewed as special cases of the Polynomial Congruence Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Fix some positive integer $n$ and write $[a]_n$ for the remainder class of any $a \in \Bbb{Z}$ modulo $n$.

It isn't hard to prove (try it!) that $[a+b]_n = [a]_n + [b]_n$ and $[ab]_n = [a]_n[b]_n$ for every $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$. A relation with this property is called a [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation).

In particular, this means that $[a^k]_n = [a]_n^k$ for every $a,k \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Could whoever down-voted this please be so kind to tell me *why* they did so? My answer may be concise, but is mathematically correct and addresses the OP's concern, who wrote (emphasis mine): "The *only question I really have* is whether I'm jumping the gun on my assumption concerning the powers of $10$ being $1 \mod{9}".

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}653854-(6+5+3+8+5+4)&=6\cdot99999+5\cdot9999+3\cdot999+8\cdot99+5\cdot9\\
&=(6\cdot11111+5\cdot1111+3\cdot111+8\cdot11+5)\cdot9.
\end{align}$$

A number and the sum of its digits differ by a multiple of $9$.